# Stack Overflow Survey results don't display properly in Firefox

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, stack-overflow-developer-survey

The error is noticed when visiting the [Most Loved, Dreaded, and Wanted Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/research/developer-survey-2015#tech-super) page and switching to the "Most Wanted" tab. The first two results (Android and Javascript) do not appear correctly in Firefox. See below:

> [image: Bars at 100%]

This is because the CSS rules that define the widths for these two bars are incorrect:

```css
.bar-set.super-wanted ul li.super-android {
  width: 17.7%%;
}

.bar-set.super-wanted ul li.super-android span {
  left: 17.7%%;
}

.bar-set.super-wanted ul li.super-javascript {
  width: 15.4%%;
}
```

Note that the percentage symbol appears *twice* for each of these values. Apparently, Chrome doesn't care about this and just removes the second symbol and treats it as a percentage. But Firefox, on the other hand, treats this error as an invalid value and completely drops the entire property, so no width gets applied at all and the bar expands to a 100% width - it's default behavior.

Comment: You're a dev now, go fix it! ;)

Comment: Works in **Opera** (not talking about Chropera)

Comment: @Sha - that's news to him and to the core team ;)

Comment: @Oded but.. but.. "employee with Stack Exchange" plus 25K rep on SO, doesn't it mean a dev? ;)

Comment: [Does it?](http://stackoverflow.com/users/811/shog9), @Sha, does it?

Comment: @Oded lol, and you tell me Shog can't push a fix if he really wants to? :D

Comment: @ShadowWizard It's bad enough that they're letting me and Oded touch code, you want to let Shog9 in as well?? You monster.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[status-d'oh], really.

Pushing a fix; will be all set in the next build.

Thanks!